# Setting up two Wi-Fi routers into one network

Tags: networking, router

Here is my story: I have 3 routers:

- Router 0: [UPVEL UR-315BN](http://upvel.com/items/ur-315bn.html) (faulty and has weak Wi-Fi signal) is located in a store room. (I can't use its Wi-Fi except in the range of 3-4 meters. Currently, the Wi-Fi is off, and I don't plan to use it). It is plugged with my ISP ethernet cable.
- Router A: Asus RT-N66U is connected with UPVEL by [DC powerline](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?categoryid=1657&model=TL-PA251KIT). It has one USB that I want to use with HDD, streaming movies to Smart TVs through DLNA.
- Router B: Asus RT-N53 is connected with UPVEL by ethernet connection.

These two letter routers has no possible wired connection (they are situated in two opposite ends of my flat).

I want to set up this network to, for example, stream movies from router A to TVs connected to the router B, 
or, to send (over Apple's AirPrint (Bonjour service)) documents with iPad connected to the B router to printer, connected to the router A.
I'm sorry, but it seems that I can't post more than 2 links. And yes, I googled this problem, but I could not find any solution for my configuration and my limits (Router A and B can't be connected with cable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the DHCP-capabilities of your "Router 0" (UPVEL) you can disable the DHCP on both the A and B router.

You **need** to plug the cable (from the UPVEL, ethernet for B and powerline for A ones) in an available **LAN-port** (leaving the WAN-port of these routers unused). You can use the other LAN-ports for computer and devices. They will get an IP from "Router 0".

Now you can reach all the connected computers/devices through every router. (no need to connect A to B because they are both connected to 0.)

(You may want to set the IP of router A and B to a static one within the range of your network so you can reach them for administrative purposes)

Example:

```
Router 0: Static IP 192.168.1.1 / DHCP 192.168.1.100 - 192.168.1.200
Router A: Static IP 192.168.1.2 / DHCP Off
Router B: Static IP 192.168.1.3 / DHCP Off
```

Comment: thanks for helping me! But doesn't that mean that this will increase CPU load on the Router-0? We now have 7 devices that are constantly connected to Wi-Fi and it can b up to 10-12.

Comment: Seeing the LAN-ports of the UPVEL-router this shouldn't be a problem. They are "10/100Mbps". You could go up to 200Mbps with the dc powerline but the ethernet of RT-N53 is also 100Mbps. So only the devices on the RT-N66U could get 1000Mbps **between them self**. Any traffic to the RT-N53 would end up limited to 100Mbps. So if that goes over the UPVEL-router (also 100Mpbs) it does not limit the speed. Only if you have 5 devices, each pulling down **more** than 20Mbps at the same time on the RT-N66U from a device on the UPVEL side you could see slow down. But the change of that seems remote.

Comment: BTW you say the UPVEL is faulty. In what way? Just the WiFi part or is it completely unstable, also for wired connections? For a normal router 10-20 connected computer shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It's unstable when there are 2 or more wireless clients.   Btw, has anyone used 'media server' feature on Asus routers? I setted it up, now I can upload movies through FTP to the USB thumbdrive in RT-N66U, or even add torrent file in 'download master' (then I can easily watch them on my TVs through DLNA). The only feature I need and couldn't set up is to get access to this router (Router A) through the Internet (to be able remotely download torrents). I have public static IP address. I tried to play with DMZ and Port Forwarding settings, but I didn't get any luck. I apologize for an offtopic.

Comment: I wouldn't place `Router A` in the DMZ. Your question (remotely download torrents) was buried deep in your comment so maybe you should better ask it as a new question. At least it will get a lot more attention then a comment on an (already accepted) answer. But what exactly is the problem with forwarding a port on the `UPVEL` to the `Router A` on `192.168.1.2`? It depends on the torrent-app which ports.